# How to find element in selenium using this html link

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Add Farmers

I have a link button in my form all things are same in button just id is different
like in this id is (10274) same different button have different id how to click and enter particular  button please help

Comment: <a class="buttontext" href="javascript:addFarmer(10274)">Add Farmers</a>

Comment: //a[text()='Add Farmers']

Comment: I was try this it's not work please tell how to find and enter using href which have java script added                                                                                          Means how to find this href="javascript:addFarmer(10275) in selenium

Comment: Can you please share the html code of the button.

Comment: //a[contains(@href,'javascript:addFarmer(10274)') and text()='Add Farmers']  , You can provide the substring as well.

Comment: <a class="buttontext" href="javascript:addFarmer(10274)">Add Farmers</a>                   This is my HTML code

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//a[text()='Add Farmers'][1]"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html                This error displaying continue

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the HTML and other relevant info so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
// Get the starting id of the Add Farmers button
int firstId = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Add Farmers'][1]")).getAttribute("href").split("(")[1].replace(")",""));

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@href, '" + (firstId+1) + "')]")).click();
```

The above code will get the first id of the Add Farmers link and below locator will click on any button. Hope this helps.